# Reference cells in an inputBox

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, inputbox

...

[image]

This user interface above exists for input boxes on Excel through VBA. The code for creating these input boxes goes something like this:

```
Set List1 = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Selecciona lista fija.", Type:=8)
List1.Select
```

Now I'm trying to find a way of doing this in Google Spreadsheets. It seems to me that this is not possible through the [Class Browser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser?hl=en) or [UI service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp?hl=en).

Comment: You can sure do an input box with apps script and invoke it from a menu or button.
Why do you think it cant be done with uiServices? What have you tried that didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open issue / enhancement request on data validation](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=219), you can star it to keep informed if it becomes available